# Set hyphenation with polyglossia

Tags: babel, hyphenation, polyglossia

If `babel` doesn't know how to hyphenate a word, I can inform it of good line breaks with `\babelhyphenation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
    \babelhyphenation[nynorsk]{fram-halds-skulen}
\begin{document}
framhaldsskulen
\end{document}
```

But how do I do this with [`polyglossia`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia)? The documentation doesn't say anything about it. `\babelhyphenation` obviously doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}
    \babelhyphenation[nynorsk]{fram-halds-skulen}
\begin{document}
framhaldsskulen
\end{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 ^^I\babelhyphenation
                        [nynorsk]{fram-halds-skulen}
?
```

Comment: I would assume you can use `\hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}` as long as the right language is in scope at that point

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, I only tried ``\hyphenation[nynorsk]{fram-halds-skulen}``, which didn't work. Then how will ``polyglossia`` understand what language the hyphenation is for if I just set ``\hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}``?

Comment: it's a tex primitive it is the same mechanism as tex knows which hyphenation table to use for text at that point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As usual, in the example the lines are overfull on purpose, so as to force hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{nynorsk}

\begin{hyphenrules}{nynorsk}
\hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use the same trick of `\begin{hyphenrules}` if you have different languages in your document and want to add some hyphenation rules for single words.

---

A possibly better interface:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sethyphenation[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcsundef{#2@loaded}
    {\xpg@nogloss{#2}}
    {\setkeys{#2}{#1}\xpg@set@language{#2}%
     \hyphenation{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}
\@onlypreamble\sethyphenation
\makeatother


\setmainlanguage{nynorsk}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\sethyphenation{nynorsk}{fram-halds-skulen}

\sethyphenation{english}{tes-t-word}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen testword}

\selectlanguage{english}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen testword}

\end{document}
```

The `\sethyphenation` command accepts also an optional argument such as `variant=british`, but at the moment it wouldn't do much good, because the same option to `\selectlanguage` doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]

Comment: Ah! ``\begin{hyphenrules}``!

Comment: @Sverre Yes, `babel` 3.9 uses a similar trick, but defines the `\babelhyphenation` command; there's no corresponding command in `polyglossia`, currently.

Comment: Just an extra note regarding variants, it is not quite clear what language argument one should pass to `hypenrules`.  In the case of `\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}` it turns out one needs `\begin{hyphenrules}{ukenglish}...`, which I discovered by checking `lua`'s messages in the `log` file.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Why? `\begin{hyphenrules}{english}` will choose the British hyphenation patterns, with that declaration for `\setmainlanguage` (which should be used instead of `\setdefaultlanguage`, although they're synonyms).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not happen for a `\begin{hyphenrules}{english}` in the preamble with `lualatex`.  You new code example throws the error `! LuaTeX error ...e/2014/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:60: l
uatex-hyphen: \language0 should be dumped in the format` at the `l.29 \selectlanguage{english}` too

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'd say that is a bug in LuaLaTeX/polyglossia (either or both); you solve it by saying `\setotherlanguage{english}` before `\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}`

Comment: If the word to be hyphenated contains a hyphen itself (such as “non-degenerate”), how would one write the `\hyphenation` command for it?

Comment: @RuudvA You don't. By rule, TeX breaks words with explicit hyphens only at those hyphens.

Comment: Then why won't this simple code work, with different `hyphenrules` for the two languages? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguage{german}
\begin{hyphenrules}{english}
\hyphenation{Au-ße-ro-rd-en-tl-ic-hk-eit}
\end{hyphenrules}
\begin{hyphenrules}{german}
\hyphenation{Auß-ero-rde-nt-lic-hke-it}
\end{hyphenrules}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Außerordentlichkeit \textgerman{Außerordentlichkeit}}
\end{document}`

Comment: I realized it's for the same reason as mentioned above with `ukenglish`. The `hyphenrules` need the names from `babel`, so swapping `german` with `ngerman` will do the trick.