# hyphenrules no longer defined in polyglossia

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

I've used `hyphenrules` to add custom hyphenation to the languages I write in. I once asked how to do this, and the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213166/set-hyphenation-with-polyglossia/213168#213168) (MWE below) no longer compiles, but gives the error message `Environment hyphenrules undefined`.

So the question is, how should one add language specific custom hyphenation rules with `polyglossia` now? I'm using version 1.49 of `polyglossia`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{nynorsk}

\begin{hyphenrules}{nynorsk}
\hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen}

\end{document}
```

EDIT

Following [Ulrike's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550978/hyphenrules-no-longer-defined-in-polyglossia#comment1391462_550978), I've tried to follow section 5.1 in the [polyglossia documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), where it says we can use the command `\xpghyphenation`. Doing so, however, only gives me the error message `Undefined control sequence. l.6 \xpghyphenation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{nynorsk}

\xpghyphenation{nynorsk}{fram-halds-skulen}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see the documentation. Section "Adapting hyphenation".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It says that we should use `\xpghyphenation`. I've tried, but only get the error `Undefined control sequence. l.6 \xpghyphenation`.

Comment: Ok, I've found that `\xpghyphenation` is a typo, see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/413. It has for some reason still not been corrected in the documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/427 (though in my head at least the point of `hyphenrules` was not to give hyphenation exceptions in the preamble, it is to *use* only the hyphenation patterns of the specified language)

Answer (score 1):

The environment `hyphenrules` is deprecated in newer versions of `polyglossia`. To add language specific hyphenations, use `\pghyphenation[(options)]{(language)}{(hyphenations)}`. The current [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) (v. 1.49) states incorrectly in section 5.1 that the command is `\xpghyphenation`. This is [a mistake](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/413) for `\pghyphenation` which has yet to be corrected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant = nynorsk]{norwegian}

\pghyphenation[variant = nynorsk]{norwegian}{fram-halds-skulen}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/427 I think the first sentence is misleading. It might be true though that it is deprecated for this particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

From TeX primitive point of view you needs only to use `\heyphenation` primitive when `\language` primitive register is set to the selected language. So, you can write:

```
{\language=lang.number \hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}}
```

A little problem is that if you are using LaTeX then you don't know the lang.number because it is auto-generated by macros. You can set the `\language` register using LaTeX's command:

```
\selectlanguage{nynorsk}
```

This command does `\language=lang.number` internally. So, you can use the `\hyphenation` primitive by:

```
{\selectlanguage{nynorsk} \hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}}
```

Of course, you can give hyphenation exceptions for all declared languages:

```
 {\selectlanguage{nynorsk} \hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}}
 {\selectlanguage{czech}   \hyphenation{výjme-čné dě-lení}}
 ...
```

For sake of complexity: if you are using csplain or OpTeX format then you know the number of your language, see `hyphen.lan` file. Norwegian Nynorsk in Unicode has language 136. So, you can do your task at primitive level only:

```
{\language=136 \hyphenation{fram-halds-skulen}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hyphenrules` trick was a hack. Since version 1.45, `polyglossia` has a specific method for defining language specific hyphenation exceptions, namely

```
\pghyphenation[<options>]{<language>}{<exception list>}
```

The `<options>` are for the particular language to set a variant. The `<exception list>` has the same syntax as the argument to `\hyphenation`, so words separated by spaces with hyphens at the chosen break points.

As of version 1.50a, the documentation about hyphenation exceptions is inaccurate, because it is claimed that `\hyphenation` acts globally for all language, but this is not true: the exceptions are just for the *current* language which, in the preamble is still language 0 (American English).

Thus `\hyphenation` should actually never be used (unless the main language is American English).

The `hyphenrules` environment has not been deprecated, but it should only be used in the document body. On the other hand, as of version 1.50a the `hyphenrules` trick still works. This doesn't mean it should be used, but older documents using it will work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=nynorsk]{norwegian}

\pghyphenation[variant=nynorsk]{norwegian}{fram-halds-skulen}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}framhaldsskulen}

\end{document}
```

[image]